# Count category occurence in pandas data row

Tags: python, pandas

i have  fairly simple question but could not find the answer somehow.
My Pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
           0        1        2       3   ....
fruit   apple   apple   banana   apple   ....
county   ....   ....    ....      ....   ....
```

basically I want to count the different fruit types and plot them in a bar plot with X axis beeing the categories and Y beeing the number of occurrences.

I tried `df["fruit"].value_counts()` with .plot but apparently i always get a key error as it doesn't seem to be a valid row key?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataframes follow a tabular format where the convention is to have features as columns and entries as rows. So you need to [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) your dataframe. After that `df["fruit"]` will give what you expect.

Comment: ok wow, didn't know this. That solved it, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `fruit` is in your dataframe index. If so, use:

```
df.loc['fruit'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly straightforward. transpose will give you columns as rows so now you can

```
df.T["fruit"].value_counts()
```